# Destructive interference of waves

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, energy-conservation, interference, superposition

If 2 waves have the same frequency and amplitude moving over each other but one of them is ahead of the second so that the phase difference is pi "half wave length" so a perfect and complete destructive interference occur,, in that case what happens to the energy? And where does it go?

Comment: [This](http://puhep1.princeton.edu/~mcdonald/examples/destructive.pdf) paper answers your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Destructive interference and energy conservation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/370371/)