# How come $P=Fv$ applies to light?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, visible-light, photons, pressure

I was asked the following question in a physics worksheet:

> A $2.0 \,\mathrm{mW}$ laser is shone onto a metal plate. The cross-sectional area of the beam is $4.0\times 10^{-6} \, \mathrm m^2$. Assume all light is absorbed, and the laser is emits all light at $4.7\times 10^{14} \, \mathrm{Hz}$. Calculate the pressure due to the light.

My current approach was along the lines of:
$$\begin{aligned}
p &=\dfrac{hf}{c}\\
&=\dfrac{h\times4.7\times10^{14}}{3\times10^{8}}\\
&=1.0\times10^{-27}\mathrm{Ns}\\
\end{aligned}$$
$$\begin{aligned}
f_{e^-}&=\tfrac{P}{E}=\tfrac{P}{hf}\\
&=\dfrac{2.0\times 10^{-3}}{hf}\\
&=6.45\times10^{15}\mathrm{Hz}\\
\end{aligned}$$
$$\begin{aligned}
F&=\frac{\mathrm dp}{\mathrm dt}\\
&=p\times f_{e^-}\\
&=6.7\times10^{-12}\mathrm{N}\\
\end{aligned}$$
$$\begin{aligned}
P&=\frac{F}{A}\\
&=\frac{6.7\times 10^{-12}}{4.0\times 10^{-6}}\\
&=1.7\times 10^{-6}\mathrm{Pa}
\end{aligned}$$

But a classmate of mine used $P=Fv$ (i.e. power used to propel a point mass is equal to the force applied to that mass times the velocity of that mass) to solve for the force, and I don’t understand how that equation, which is used in linear kinematics, applies to a massless particle.

I understand the principle that light exerts pressure, but why does this formula which was derived for something entirely different apply in this context?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If I'm floating in space and I turn on a flashlight, will I accelerate?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/112866/)

Comment: Please check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_pressure)

Comment: For a beam of light, regarded as an unquantised electromagnetic wave, or as a stream of photons, we can show that $$\text{momentum carried past a point per unit time}=\frac{\text{beam power}}c.$$ Assuming that all the light is absorbed by the surface, then Newton's second and third laws show this to be the force that the light exerts on the surface.  We can clearly write this in the form $F=\frac{\text{power}}c$, but it doesn't aid (my) understanding.

Comment: I believe this question is *similar* but certainly not the same or equivalent to one indicated. A complete answer to this question may provide new information not existing in the other one, therefore should not be closed.