# What’s the equal/opposite reaction of a laser beam hitting something?

Tags: particle-physics

So it goes like this; when you shoot a gun, there will be a “kick”, this is because of Newton’s third law. However, what’s the equal, and opposite reaction when a laser  ram hits an object? I need an answer as simplified as possible so I can explain this to one of my students who asked about this.
Is it heat? Is there a minuscule “kick”?

Comment: Photons have momentum, so Newton's laws still hold...

Comment: Related: [Rocket propelled by a giant monochromatic laser](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/74013/44126).

Answer (score 3):

Just treat the light as a buch of photons. Each one carries an energy depenent momentum
$$ p = \frac{E}{c} = \frac{\hbar \omega}{c} = \hbar k$$
When a photon gets absorbed, it transfers its momentum to the target. If it gets reflected, twice its momentum is transferred.

So actually, as already pointed out in a comment, you can apply classical mechanics here.

Comment: So, your saying the opposite reaction would be the deflection of the photons off the wall?

Comment: If you hold a flashlight and point it away from you, it will actually push you back due to the photon recoil.

Comment: Is this the basis for an ion engine?

Comment: @Hobo_warrior An [ion engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion_thruster) emits charged particles, not photons.